# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I read other topics on that matter like:

[Could not initialize class org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl in Spring tool Suite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50108619/could-not-initialize-class-org-hibernate-validator-internal-engine-configuration)

[Hibernate Validator java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47163434/hibernate-validator-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-could-not-initialize-class-o)

but they did no help me.

In external libraries i have only Hibernate-validator (6.0.10 version).
I use SpringBoot 2.0.3 in all poms.
I set:

```
<properties>
    <cxf.version>3.2.4</cxf.version>
    <cxf.xjc.version>3.2.1</cxf.xjc.version>
    <spring.oxm.version>4.2.4.RELEASE</spring.oxm.version>
    <aspectj.version>1.8.10</aspectj.version>
</properties>
```

The cxf 3.2.4 is from march 2018.
The cxf.xjc is from february 2018.
The Hibernate-validator is from

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Also i excluded `jboss-logging`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

In my external libraries I only have javax.validation-api 2.0.1.final
which is recommended to hibernate 6.0.13 here: 
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-gettingstarted-createproject

I set breakpoint on constructors in class `ConfigurationImpl` but it does not trigger when i run app
on tomcat 9.0.12 (not as springboot cause of business needs).

The error is:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.cxf.spring.boot.autoconfigure.CxfAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'properties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cxf-org.apache.cxf.spring.boot.autoconfigure.CxfProperties': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:155)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that i have to include jboss:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The cause of this error was this exclusion that someone made in the past.